# making steady layout position as from landscape or portrait

Tags: android

how to make the layout of the project app in android studio steady as the position i choose ,i mean how to make landscape or portrait in a steady position and don't change to vise versa as when enter  the page the layout go to those positions by it's self and don't be able to be changed even if the device state changed?

```
 < RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/inside"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp">
```

Comment: Do you want each page to specify it's layout or the whole app will have the same layout?

Comment: can you please tell me both?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do it per layout file. I think it would have to be on the base activity like my answer below

Comment: ok what about all the app to landscape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest file you can force the layout of each `Activity` like this

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyActivityName"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

    /* ... */

</activity>
```

or

```
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyActivityName"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

    /* ... */

</activity>
```